# Windows Performance Recorder: There are no trace profiles running

Tags: windows-7, windows, performance-monitor, adk

I am currently trying to analyze the startup and login performance on a Windows 7 64bit machine. I therefor installed ADK 8.1 and fired up the `Windows Performance Recorder` (wprui.exe).

As I am running this on 64bit I disabled `PagingExecutive` using `wpr.exe -disablepagingexecutive on`, rebooted the machine and double-checked it's set within the registry under:

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\DisablePagingExecutive = 1`

Then I started recording using the following parameters from the GUI:

```
Performance scenario: boot
Detail Level: Verbose
Logging mode: file
Number of iterations: 1
```

...and checked exclusively `"First level triage"`

When I restart the utility after a clean reboot & login it tells me:

`There are no trace profiles running. Error code: 0xc5583000`

What am I doing wrong here? Unfortunately I can't find anything regarding the mentioned error code.

Comment: You have plenty of free storage space?

Comment: don't use the ugly GUI, use the good old xbootmgr: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE

Comment: have you captured a trace with xbootmgr? Should I take a look at it?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the proposal. Unfortunately I can't hand out the data. Is there a way to analyze the group policy processing in more detail? Like how many time has been spend on executing a specific script etc.

Comment: GP runs in WinlogonInit, so look at this part of the trace and look for disk/network/CPU activity.